# Parse through each element of an array in pyspark and apply substring

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

Hi I have a pyspark dataframe with an array col shown below.

I want to iterate through each element and fetch only string prior to hyphen and create another column.

```
+------------------------------+
|array_col                     |
+------------------------------+
|[hello-123, abc-111]          |
|[hello-234, def-22, xyz-33]   |
|[hiiii-111, def2-333, lmn-222]|
+------------------------------+
```

Desired Output;

```
+------------------------------+--------------------+
|col1                          |new_column          |
+------------------------------+--------------------+
|[hello-123, abc-111]          |[hello, abc]        |
|[hello-234, def-22, xyz-33]   |[hello, def, xyz]   |
|[hiiii-111, def2-333, lmn-222]|[hiiii, def2, lmn]  |
+------------------------------+--------------------+
```

I am trying something like below but I could not apply a regex/substring inside a udf.

```
cust_udf = udf(lambda arr: [x for x in arr],ArrayType(StringType()))
df1.withColumn('new_column', cust_udf(col("col1")))
```

Can anyone please help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **`Spark-2.4`** use **`transform`** higher order function.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show(10,False)
#+---------------------------+
#|array_col                  |
#+---------------------------+
#|[hello-123, abc-111]       |
#|[hello-234, def-22, xyz-33]|
#+---------------------------+

df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- array_col: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *


df.withColumn("new_column",expr('transform(array_col,x -> split(x,"-")[0])')).\
show()
#+--------------------+-----------------+
#|           array_col|       new_column|
#+--------------------+-----------------+
#|[hello-123, abc-111]|     [hello, abc]|
#|[hello-234, def-2...|[hello, def, xyz]|
#+--------------------+-----------------+
```